# Appdomain initialization exception while run nunit test

Tags: c++, wpf, nunit

I have WPF application that I am trying to run through nunit test.
I am getting the following Exception:

```
"the c++ module failed to load during appdomain initialization".
```

This problem appers in C++ DLL that I have reference to.

It is important to note that there is no problem to run the project not through nunit.

Comment: Does it also say "The system cannot find the file specified" ?

Comment: "This runtime has refused to evaluate the expression at this time". In addition , when i look inside the exception that the dll threw:"could not load type *someType from assembly *someDll"